# Function check number return to image in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to create function replace number to image?
Example: `var dd="123"`
I want to create function replace value of `dd` to `image`.

```
if 1=image1
if 2=image2
if 3=image3
```

How to do that? Please provide coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
function imageReplace ( str ) {
    var arr = str.split('');
    var returnArr = new Array();
    for(var i in arr ){
        returnArr.push("image"+arr[i]);
    }
    return returnArr;
}
```

I think thats what your looking for

Comment: Dear your coding not working. dd=123 how to create function convert 123 to image if 1=image1 if 2=image2 if 3=image3 best regards

Comment: I don't know what that means... perhaps updating the question with a little more info. I just took a stab at what I thought you meant.

Comment: dear sir. example var dd=312 .so i want to convert dd value to image.if dd=3 so ur coding catch image3.gif, if dd=1 ur coding catch image1, if dd=2 so ur coding catch image2. Best regards

Comment: Result=dd=312 (image3.gif,image1.gif,imag2.gif)

Comment: this function returns an array like this, ['image3', 'image2', 'image1'] you want it to return a string like "312 (image3.gif,image1.gif,imag2.gif)"?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer because of the lack of expected flow control, but something like this:

```
function concatFilename(str,index)
{
   return 'image'+str[index];
}
```

Usage:

```
var dd = 'abc123';
for (var i=0; i < dd.length; i++)
{
  console.log(concatFilename(dd, index));      
}
```

Or... easier:

```
dd[2] = 'c';
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `dd` contain a single number, to be converted as a whole? If so:

```
var dd = '123';
dd.replace(/([\d]+)/, /image$1/);  // 'image123'
```

If you want each digit to be converted:

```
var dd = '123';
dd.replace(/([\d])/, /image$1/);  // 'image1image2image3'
```

Hope that helps. :)

Honestly, I'm assuming you almost certainly want the first of the two. (If in doubt, ask yourself -- what behavior do you expect if you're on image 10 or 11?)

Comment: some dd=34433 is random number sir.

Comment: Then you want the first of the two code samples I offered. It will work for any arbitrary positive integer.

Comment: can you provide full script ?

Comment: What full script? I only wrote code specifically to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getImages = function(s) {
  var images=[], ss=(""+s).split(''), len=ss.length, i;
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    images.push("image" + ss[i] + ".gif");
  }
  return images;
};
getImages(123); // => ["image1.gif", "image2.gif", "image3.gif"]
getImages(42); // => ["image4.gif", "image2.gif"]
getImages(0); // => ["image0.gif"]
```

**[Edit]** or perhaps something like this?

```
var getImageNames = function(s) {
  return (""+s).split('').map(function(x) {
    return '"image'+x+'.gif"';
  }).join(' ');
}
getImageNames(123); // => '"image1.gif" "image2.gif" "image3.gif"'
```

Comment: Dear if i want to replace , to space. how can sir?

Comment: @user: something like `getImages(123).join(' ')`?  I am not sure what you are asking - please update your question with more details for all to see.

Comment: this is result ["image4.gif", "image2.gif"] i dont  need symbol (,).how can i replace , to blank....best regards

Comment: @user: the result is an array, try using its "join" function, per my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to replace each digit with an image tag:

```
dd = dd.replace(/(\d)/g, '<img src="image$1.gif" alt="$1" />');
```

This also works on a string containing numbers, like `"Page 12 of 42"` is turned into `"Page <img src="image1.gif" alt="1" /><img src="image2.gif" alt="2" /> of <img src="image4.gif" alt="4" /><img src="image2.gif" alt="2" />"`.